# Want hide directory nginx but didnt lost the content

Tags: nginx, hide, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

I have folder images, css, class, js, includes at my application.
and if somebody access that folder --> `403 Forbidden`

I want custom this output `403 Forbidden` ---> `404 Not Found`

I'll try this code

`location ~ /(.*)/{ return 404; }`

It was sucessfull, the output `404 Not Found`
but my images,   css, class, js, includes LOST at my application.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
location  = /THAT_FOLDER/ { return 404; }

Directives with the "=" prefix that match the query exactly (literal string). 
If found, searching stops.
```

ref: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location